# SQL Server - NULL value in calculation results in NULL Result

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've got this issue that I'm sure everyone else who's worked with MSSQL has dealt with:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (
    value1 DECIMAL(10,2)
    , value2 DECIMAL(10,2)
);

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (1.00, NULL); 

SELECT value1 + value2 FROM #temp
```

If I run the last `value1 + value2` query, rather than getting the expected result (`1.00`), it returns `NULL` when one of the values I'm including in the calculation is `NULL`. This is causing all kinds of grief in my reports because the query isn't returning the right value when one of my inputs is `NULL`.

Is there a workaround for the above to get the expected `1.00` result instead of `NULL`, such that the `NULL` second value is treated as zero?

Comment: wrap potential null values in isnull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You could use `ISNULL(value2, 0)`.

eg. `select isnull(value1, 0) + isnull(value2, 0);`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT coalesce(value1,0) + coalesce(value2,0) FROM #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding anything to NULL results in NULL because NULL is unknown. You can avoid it by using coalesce or an ISNULL. I most commonly see this in people generating strings and they are not expecting NULL values in a field.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (
    value1 DECIMAL(10,2)
    , value2 DECIMAL(10,2)
);

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (1.00, NULL); 

SELECT ISNULL(value1,0) + ISNULL(value2,0) FROM #temp
```